# maven - proxy - Could not transfer artifact. (Proxy corporativo)

Tags: maven, proxy, eclipse-oxygen

Maven no descarga las librerías de https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven

Estoy intentando descargar el repositorio de maven para crear una aplicación Java. Si lo hago desde casa sí funciona porque no tengo un proxy, si lo hago desde la empresa no descarga aunque configure el proxy en settings.xml.

1. Identifiqué el proxy para conectarse a Internet:
   IE --> Internet options --> Connections --> LAN settings

   *** En mi caso la pestaña Connections estabs deshabilitada y la habilitaron desde el registro: regedit --> Equipo\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Polices\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\ --> ConnectionsTab = 0
2. Modifiqué el archivo ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml para incluir el proxy y puerto:

   ```
   <proxy>
     <id>optional</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <username>[user]</username>
     <password>[password]</password>
     <host>[proxy]</host>
     <port>8080</port>
     <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
   ```
3. Al ejecutar cualquier comando de maven me muestra el error:

> [WARNING] NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
>
> [WARNING] NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials

4.Intenté pasar los datos del proxy por parámetro pero aún así no funciona:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS="-DsocksProxyHost=[proxy] -DsocksProxyPort=8080"
```

5. Al parecer es un tema de autenticación, ya intenté con distintas combinaciones en el username (usuario, dominio/usuario, dominio\usuario, usuario@server_correo) pero no funciona.

maven lo ejecuto desde línea de comando y desde eclipse. Ya consulté varios post de stack y varios sugieren poner bien el proxy y cambiar el archivo eclipse.ini con esto:

> -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4

Sin embargo, sigue sin funcionar. Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1):

Seguí buscando y encontré este post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539048/maven-behind-a-auto-generated-proxy

Al final viene el comentario de xuesheng, tomé la solución que indica y funcionó:

Se debe copiar el jar `wagon-http-lightweight` dentro de la carpeta `lib/ext` (https://codepen.io/ugbandula/post/how-to-configure-maven-to-work-with-ntlm-proxies)